# Hibernate doesn't allow nullable foreign key in OneToMany relationship

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to make a foreign key nullable using JPA.

I have two entities with a `OneToMany` relationship:

```
@Entity
public class PersonEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "company_id", nullable = true)
    @ManyToOne(optional = true, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private CompanyEntity company;

}


@Entity
public class CompanyEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "company")
    private List<PersonEntity > personEntityList;

}
```

I want to be able to save a `PersonEntity` with a null `CompanyEntity`.

But when I try

```
PersonEntity john = new PersonEntity();
person.setName("John")
personRepository.save(john)
```

Hibernate complains about my entity having a `null` company_id:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "company_id" violates not-null constraint
```

When I check the SQL generated by Hibernate for this column, I see it indeed as a `NOT NULL` constraint:

```
alter table person_entity
    add company_id serial not null;
```

How can I make `company_id` nullable in the relation `PersonEntity` ?

Edit:

I use Hibernate with `PostgreSQLDialect`

Comment: What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I use PostgreSQLDialect. I edited my answer with this information